# Scrapy Dynamic Item Class Creation

Tags: python, scrapy

Unsure of how to create a dynamic item class: http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#dynamic-creation-of-item-classes

Not quite sure where I would use that code provided in the documentation. 
Would I stick this in pipelines.py, items.py and call this from the parse function of the spider? or the main script file that calls the scrapy spider?

Answer (score 1):

I would place the code snippet in `items.py`, and use it in the `spider` for any dynamic item I need (probably down to personal preferences), for example:

```
from myproject.items import create_item_class

# base on one of the scrapy example...    
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    # ... name, allowed_domains ... 
    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
        # for need to use a dynamic item
        field_list = ['id', 'name', 'description']
        DynamicItem = create_item_class('DynamicItem', field_list)
        item = DynamicItem()
        # then you can use it here...
        item['id'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
        item['description'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

You may be interested to read the [Dynamic Creation of Item Classes #398](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/398) for a better understanding.

Comment: If I want it to be a persistent item class (i.e after getting field values more than one page would use the same xpaths/field-values) would I put this right inside of def __init__(self,**kw) instead? and then call it from the parse function like so: item = self.DynamicItem() ?

Comment: @GFix, yes you can do that too, but if the DynamicItem having the same fields is going to be reused occasionally, I'd prefer to create an item in `items.py`.

Comment: @GFix, normally I only use this snippet for some interesting items I found outside of the routine, you can say kind of one-off.

Comment: @GFix, what's the output of xpaths? It's hard to explain in comments. You'd better open a new question.